# EDID emulation in HDMI and DisplayPort, is DisplayPort really more difficult?

Tags: display, hdmi, specifications, displayport

I've been doing a lot research on EDID and HDMI and DisplayPort and I have a question about the relative difficulty of always-on EDID Emulation between the two specs.

With HDMI, almost every Matrix Switch over $200 USD supports always-on EDID emulation. This keeps all of your displays and inputs in the dark about whether or not they're even connected. This is useful because if you have one monitor, and two inputs, both of those inputs think they *always* connected to the monitor. The parlance for this in the consumer documentation is that the EDID is emulated. This has the added benefit of keeping the monitor primed to switch between inputs, even when the Matrix Switch isn't providing an active video stream.

**My question is on the DisplayPort spec, and how it compared to the HDMI spec: I've been using HDMI for years now just for this feature. Why isn't the EDID Emulation feature found on any DisplayPort switches?** Even companies that sell *both* disclaim this buy saying EDID Emulation isn't available on the DisplayPort variant. What, if anything, makes DisplayPort switches and KVMs that much harder to implement?

- [4 Port Dual Monitor KVM Switch DP 4K60Hz with Cascading](https://www.tesmart.com/collections/dual-monitor/products/tesmart-dual-monitor-kvm-switch-4-displayport-pcs-2-displayport-monitors-updated-4k-60hz-support-cascading-for-quad-monitor)
- [4 Port Dual Monitor KVM Switch HDMI 4K60Hz with Cascading](https://www.tesmart.com/collections/dual-monitor/products/tesmart-hdmi-dual-monitor-kvm-switch4x2)

Note, only the DP one says,

> This version does not support EDID, please contact the customer service team for more information.

And again from [this FAQ](https://www.kvm-switches-online.com/cs782dp.html),

> DisplayPort is a data cable instead of a video cable like DVI or HDMI - DisplayPort KVM Switches (including the CS1942 and CS782DP) do not include video EDID emulation (or for Aten: "Video DataSync"). It is typical to notice a slight delay in switching a DisplayPort based KVM. If you are looking for a KVM with EDID emulation, I would recommend going with a HDMI based KVM (i.e. Aten CS1792 ) or a DVI based KVM (i.e. Aten CS1762A).

Comment: Not accurate enough for an answer, but HDMI chips, matrix or not, support showing EDID on their input, and maybe DP switch chips also switch the AUX lanes and are literally just switches that don't look or process what is communicated between source and sink. But it does not matter, as you can enable EDID emulation on your video card so the driver does not check or care if a monitor is really connected.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis appears based on a single manufacturer that doesn't offer that capability.  I have a 2-port dual display DisplayPort KVM from ConnectPro and it works well.  EDID is on full-time.  I bought mine roughly 3 years ago and love it.  There weren't any similarly capably KVMs on the market at that time.  It looks like there's a few more now, but they're significantly more expensive.

https://connectpro.com/products/udp2-12ap-displayport-1-4-kvm-switch-for-dual-monitors-and-2-systems